# Password protected WMS in Openlayers 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers, php, security, proxy

I would like to use OpenLayers to access a Wms, which is protected by a password. Unfortunately, I find no solution to this problem. My problem is in particular that I want to prevent that password from publishing in the source code of the page. I use OpenLayers 4. Can someone give me an advice?

Comment: You should use proxy. It depends on your backend. I use Asp.Net and i have proxy code in c#.

Comment: My proxy code is here: https://gist.github.com/himyata/1fde09d3cbdfa448ee45407674465060 and how to use is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387422/display-wfs-layer-in-ol3

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll test the code tonight and hope it works. I have not worked so far with proxy servers. Thanks alot!